# How to display 0 when value is 0 and in Format, # is Custom Specifier?

Tags: c#, vb.net, string-formatting

I was converting my integer value to string value by using "#" custom format like this

```
string str = string.Format("{0:###,###}", 10000);
```

So the result is "10,000".

But when value is 0 str is Empty.

```
string str = string.Format("{0:###,###}", 0);
```

I know this has been explained in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx#SpecifierD), but I want to display 0 when value is zero. How to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `###,##0` (or `#,##0`) as the format string. This will display `0` when the value is zero. You may also want to consider the [`N0`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#NFormatString) format string.

To quote [Custom Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN:

> "0": Replaces the zero with the corresponding digit if one is present; otherwise, zero appears in the result string.
>
> "#": Replaces the "#" symbol with the corresponding digit if one is present; otherwise, no digit appears in the result string.

Comment: Will `N0` be dependent on Culture?

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal: Yes, `N0` as well as `#,##0` depends on culture. In my culture (`da-DK`) the comma format specifier is displayed using a dot (e.g. `10.000`). `N0` will take culture-specific grouping into account so instead of hardcoding the groups to three digits as `#,##0` does some cultures have different rules.

Comment: Doing some further testing I have discovered the `#,##0` performs the same grouping as `N0` as far as I can see. E.g. when 12345678 is formatted using English culture (`en`) the result is `12,345,678` using either `N0` or `#,##0`. Using Hindi culture (`hi`) the result is `1,23,45,678` using the same format specifiers. Even using `#,0` will give the same result (i.e., culture specific grouping).